# instance methods and static methods in python classes

Tags: python, class, static-methods

So in python's docutils package there is a class (Image) that has a method (align). As I understood it methods take self as a first argument unless they are decorated as @classmethod or @staticmethod, however align doesn't. The relevant code is copied below ([full code here](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docutils/parsers/rst/directives/images.py)).

```
class Image(Directive):

    def align(argument):
        # This is not callable as self.align.  We cannot make it a
        # staticmethod because we're saving an unbound method in
        # option_spec below.
        return directives.choice(argument, Image.align_values)
```

I'm using this code as a base for my own purposes, and I have tried both giving align a self argument and turning it into a static method (after changing the name so as not to conflict with self.align), but got errors with either approach. What is going on?

Comment: Could you provide what error are you getting?

Comment: with @staticmethod: 'staticmethod' object is not callable. With added 'self': align_option() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'.

Comment: Actually this is documented : "This is not callable as self.align.  We cannot make it a staticmethod because we're saving an unbound method in option_spec below."

Comment: The documentation isn't very clear, though. I read that, and my first thought was "Why are you defining the function if it isn't a method?" It took me a while to realize that the function (at least, as accessed via the class attribute) wasn't intended to be used outside the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement to name the first argument `self`; that is just a convention. In the following code

```
i = Image()
i.align()
```

the `align` method will be called with the parameter `argument` referencing to the object `i`.

The following function would behave identically:

```
def align(self):
    return directives.choice(self, Image.align_values)
```

(simply replacing `argument` with the more common `self`).

---

In context, the function `align` was never intended to be a method; the author appears to simply be defining a function to store in the `options_spec` dictionary. The desired effect could have been achieved without polluting the class's namespace by deleting the name after the function reference was saved:

```
option_spec = {'alt': directives.unchanged,
               'height': directives.length_or_unitless,
               'width': directives.length_or_percentage_or_unitless,
               'scale': directives.percentage,
               'align': align,
               'name': directives.unchanged,
               'target': directives.unchanged_required,
               'class': directives.class_option}
del align
```

or by forgoing the `def` statement—it's a very simple function—and using a `lambda` expression to create the function.

```
option_spec = {'alt': directives.unchanged,
               'height': directives.length_or_unitless,
               'width': directives.length_or_percentage_or_unitless,
               'scale': directives.percentage,
               'align': lambda x: directives.choice(x, Image.align_values)
               'name': directives.unchanged,
               'target': directives.unchanged_required,
               'class': directives.class_option}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but, at least as I understand the code, what is being passed to align IS a real argument (specifically, whatever the user inputed for the align option) rather than just self with a different name. The directives.choice function checks to see if argument 1 is a member of the the tupple argument 2. Since, Image.align_values is a tupple of strings this means that argument 1 must be a string rather than an instance of class Image.

Comment: Ah, it is technically an instance method, *but* it is never intended to be used as such. Instead, the function is stored in a `dict` (`option_spec`), where is is only ever used as a regular function. Something like `i.option_spec['align'](foo)`.

Comment: It would probably have been a good idea to add `del align` after saving the reference in the `dict` so that the name is removed from the body of the `class` statement, preventing it from being stored as an attribute of the class. Then there wouldn't be a pseudo-method named `align`.

Comment: Put yet another way, the author *should* have marked it as a static method if it were intended to be accessed via the class.

Comment: Thanks for adding the edit. I'm still a little confused, but I kind of get it.